# nginx rewrite all wildcard subdomains to www.site.com

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

Using nginx, I want to redirect all subdomains of `example.com` to `www.example.com`.

I have seen redirects here to redirect non-www to www or vise versa, but I also want `www2.site.com blabla.site.com` to be redirected.
I have a wildcard dns for the domain.

For apache this can be done easily with following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The below seem to work, but it is not recommended according to the [ifisevil page](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil).

```
if ($http_host !~ "www.site.com"){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com$request_uri redirect;
}
```

Answer (score 23):

The best way to do this in nginx is with a combination of two server blocks:

```
server {
  server_name *.example.org;
  return 301 $scheme://example.org$request_uri;
}

server {
  server_name www.example.org;

  #add in further directives to serve your content
}
```

I have tested this on my laptop, since you reported it not working. I get the following result locally (after adding `www2.test.localhost` and `www.test.localhost` to my `/etc/hosts`, along with the nginx config bit, and reloading nginx):

```
$ curl --head www2.test.localhost
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.2.6
Date: Thu, 07 Mar 2013 12:29:32 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 184
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://www.test.localhost/
```

So yes, this definitely works.

Comment: Please, do not use `rewrite ^ permanent` instead of simple `return`. Executing regular expression (even so simple one `^`) is just wasting of CPU in this case.

Comment: good point, changed that

Comment: tried this, it does't work, doesn't send a 301 header not does it redirect to www.site.com actually it redirects to a different site on the server but leaver subdomain.site.com in the adressbar

Comment: anybody actually tried this, or are the codes just theory?

Comment: in the first server block  it should say
return 301 $scheme://www.example.org$request_uri;
i guess, but seeing all the answers everywhere, i'm beginning to suspect it is in the virtualmin itself
the server is running Centos6 with Virtualmins nginx's plugin
i have posted the same quesion on virtualmin's forum

Comment: It's not theory. It's how it works everyday on my site (try http://any_word_here.vbart.info ), and it's actually how it supposed to work.

Comment: this is a little different than my question though, yours strips every subdomain, i want all subdomains togo to www.site.com

Comment: well no: you have a *wildcard* serverblock for `*.example.com` and serverblock with an *exact match* for `www.example.com`. Consequently www.example.com will not be rewritten, as it is handled in the 2nd block not the first. The matching order for server_name is: 1 - exact name, 2 - longest match starting with *, 3 - longest match ending with a *, 4 - first regex match (as explained at http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name)

Comment: maybe `server_name www.example.org;` block should be in the first place if it needs to redirects?

Answer (score 13):

```
server {
    server_name .example.com;
    return 301 http://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    [...]
}
```

References:

- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html
- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html
- http://nginx.org/r/server_name
- http://nginx.org/r/return

Comment: tried this, it does't work, doesn't send a 301 header nor does it redirect to www.site.com actually it redirects to a different site on the server but leaves subdomain.site.com in the adressbar

Comment: problem is maybe that `site.com` does not match `*.site.com` (not dot).

Comment: i tried  .site.com   wich catches both *.site.com and site.com according to the manual